# em convert to px using ceil or floor and where is the css spec?

Tags: css

I know em is the relative size of font size, 
and the issue is, when font-size * em is not integer, 
like font-size: 12px * 1.4em = 16.8px, the result is 16px or 17px?
And where can I find the spec about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is described in the CSS2.1 specification here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/fonts.html#algorithm

The text reads:

> 4.'font-size' must be matched within a UA-dependent margin of tolerance. (Typically, sizes for scalable fonts are rounded to the nearest whole pixel, while the tolerance for bitmapped fonts could be as large as 20%.) Further computations, e.g., by 'em' values in other properties, are based on the computed value of 'font-size'.

So to answer your question: 16.8px **could** be mapped to 17px, but it is up to the client UA to ultimately decide how to render the text. If a display has logical sub-pixels (like Apple's Retina display, where 1 CSS pixel is actually 2x2 real pixels) then you can have non-integer pixel font sizes.

EDIT: I think I have misunderstood the specification, because modern user-agents are capable of rendering text to arbitrary sizes, even to non-integer pixel sizes. The CSS2 specification dates back to 1998 when typography on computers was different to how it is today (I don't believe you could force IE5 to render text between 12pt and 14pt, for example). So I guess this doesn't matter anymore as if you tell a modern browser to render 0.5px text it will actually give you a nice blurry blob.

Comment: Also, look in 'computed styles' in your inspector

Comment: I checked the font-size in chrome developer tools, and found it is not a integer number, so I asked this question.